# Array Split Inside Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have an object `Regions{}` which stores multiple objects, following code block showing `countryName : [regions,..,..]`

```
Regions = { Afghanistan:["Badakhshan~BDS", "Badghis~BDG", "Baghlan~BGL"]
            Albania:["Berat~01", "Dibër~09", "Durrës~02",]
          }
```

Which giving me result like this:

```
Afghanistan: Array(n)
0: "Badakhshan~BDS"
1: "Badghis~BDG"
```

what I am trying to achive is :

```
Afghanistan: Array(n)    
0:{value: "Badakhshan", lable: "BDS"}
1:{value: "Badghis", lable: "BDG"}
```

thanks in advance

PS: for the sake of some ruthless fellows following is the code what I have tried yet

```
   let countries = CountryRegionData
      let regions = {}
      countries = countries.map(country => {
        regions = {
          ...regions,
          [country[0]]: country[2].split('|')
        }
        return {
          value: country[1],
          label: country[0]
        }
      })

      console.log("countries",countries)
      console.log("regions",regions)

     let values = regions["Afghanistan"]; 
     values = values.map(value =>{
       return {
         value: value,
         lable: value
       }
     })
```

Comment: The syntax of your `Regions` object declaration looks to be invalid ATM (if the actual code has an additional comma, please add it)

Comment: yes this is just an imitation of what I am trying to achieve, actual code differs and in working state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split` and `map`, this code is changing values in original object, if you want to build a new object you can use `reduce` instead of `forEach`

```js
let Regions = {
  Afghanistan: ["Badakhshan~BDS", "Badghis~BDG", "Baghlan~BGL"],
  Albania: ["Berat~01", "Dibër~09", "Durrës~02", ]
}

Object.entries(Regions).forEach(([key,value])=>{
  Regions[key] = value.map(data=>{
    let [value,label] = data.split('~')
    return {value,label}
  })
})

console.log(Regions)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like:

```js
Regions.map(region => region.map(txt => {
  const [val, lbl] = txt.split("~");
  return { value: val, lable: lbl};
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Messy but gets the work done. Using nested `forEach` loops

```js
var Regions = {
  Afghanistan: ["Badakhshan~BDS", "Badghis~BDG", "Baghlan~BGL"],
  Albania: ["Berat~01", "Dibër~09", "Durrës~02", ]
}
var ar = [];
Object.keys(Regions).forEach(function(e) {
  Regions[e].forEach(function(k) {
    var arr = k.split('~');
    ar.push({
      value: arr[0],
      label: arr[1]
    })
  })
  Regions[e] = ar;
  ar = [];
})
console.log(Regions)
```

Comment: You can use a option called `tidy` benath the `save` button to have automatically format your code

Answer (score 1):

Use the map function to iterate the object.

```js
Regions = {
  Afghanistan: ["Badakhshan~BDS", "Badghis~BDG", "Baghlan~BGL"],
  Albania: ["Berat~01", "Dibër~09", "Durrës~02", ]
};

const finalObject = Object.keys(Regions).map(region => {
  return {
    [region]: Regions[region].map(country => {
      const [value, lable] = country.split("~");
      return {
        value,
        lable
      };
    })
  };
});

console.log(finalObject);
```